# Scratch - How can I make something like a for loop?

Tags: mit-scratch

In a traditional programming language, I would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 5; i++) {
     code here
}
```

If I needed to loop something five times, I could just use the block `repeat 5`. But if I want to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i == 5; i++) {
     if (i >= 3) {
      //Repeat piece of code after 3rd loop
     }
     //Repeated 5 times normally
}
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, just create variable and put it inside repeat loop:

[image]

Comment: A better replacement for `>=` is `not <`.

Comment: @GarethPW However, it's a *teensy* bit slower (noticeable if not on Turbo Mode), so should only be used when you need a >= on **two** variables if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is already one!

It is called the `foreach` block, and works just like a for loop.

It was removed from the block listing in the early Scratch 2.0 beta, and not many people know about it, but here is a working example on the Scratch website: [For each v in number](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/48023824/). Note that it doesn't use `%m.list` internally (i.e. it doesn't show a dropdown of all the variables), so you have to change the JSON of the project with something like [ScratchEdit](http://dx.dylan4.com/ScratchEdit/) (or a text editor) if you want to pick a variable other than `v`.

Comment: That `for each` is messed up. It it is a `for v from 1 to _`. But spelt wrong.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If you think of an integer as being the set of smaller integers (i.e. `3 = {0, 1, 2}`), but then add one to each of those numbers so you're 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed, it makes perfect sense. (But yeah, your reasoning is probably why they removed it.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor A set is an unordered list. And it would eventually bottom out with the empty set (there are no non-negative integers less than 0, so 0 = {}); fortunately, no infinite regress here. :-p [Here's the relevant Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).